# How can we extrapolate data from the 10 m climate variable (m/s) to 30 m by CDO?

Tags: netcdf, cdo-climate, grads

How can we extrapolate data from the 10 m climate variable (m/s) to 30 m by `cdo`?

We have data (m/s) in NC file.  obsfile1.nc

You can see the power law method (for extrapolation) in the equation.
Please see the attached screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the expression, (H30/H10)**alfa = 1.166 so you can just use `mulc`

```
cdo mulc,1.166 in_10u.nc out_30u.nc
```

As a side comment, in general though I think it would be a poor method, would be much better to use MO stability functions to account for the presence or not of a stable or neutral boundary layer. Stull's 1988 textbook Boundary Layer Meteorology is a classic and a good reference for this (and available online).